# Lists in django: show a certain tag after 3 items

Tags: python, arrays, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Django and I'm trying to generate Bootstrap rows and columns to display records from a database. After every three records, a new row should be added. So if I have 9 records, this is the code that should display:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
</div>
```

Right now I have this code:

```
<div class="row">
{% for info in list %}
  <div class="col-lg-4">{{ info.title }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

This generates:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">item</div>
</div>
```

How do I make the extra row tags appear after every 3 records?

Comment: why not send a list containing 3 items where each item is a list of 3 items. That way you won't have to go through so much trouble in templates

Comment: That sounds great but how would I do that?? I currently get the list from a database using: `list = News.objects.order_by('title')`. Is there a way to get that split up in groups of three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#div):

```
<div class="row">
{% for info in list %}
  <div class="col-lg-4">{{ info.title }}</div>
  {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this won't close the div tag unexpectedly.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I suppose all divs will be closed, but in case of total cout is divisible by 3 it just add additional empty div block.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work great. Empty div in some cases, but not a big problem.